# CI SMTP gmail sending

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp

email is getting send at local but giving error when site uploaded
here is code of library  please help

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Emaillib {

    function send_email($fromEmail, $fromName, $details) {
        $CI = & get_instance();
        $CI->load->library('email');

        $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
        $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
        $config['smtp_port'] = '465';
        $config['smtp_timeout'] = '7';
        $config['smtp_user'] = 'abc@gmail.com'; // Email
        $config['smtp_pass'] = '*****'; // Password
        $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
        $config['newline'] = "\r\n";
        $config['mailtype'] = 'html'; // or html
        $config['validation'] = TRUE; // bool whether to validate email or not

        $CI->email->initialize($config);

        $CI->email->from($fromEmail, $fromName);
        $CI->email->to('abc@xyz.com'); // To Email
        $CI->email->reply_to($fromEmail, $fromName);

        $CI->email->subject('Enquiry through Website');
        $CI->email->message($details);

        $isSent = $CI->email->send();
        //echo $CI->email->print_debugger();

        if (!$isSent) {
            return 'false';
        }
        return 'success';
    }

}
```

?>

Comment: Check your ports - 465 might not be open

Comment: email is successful at localhost..problem when site is uploaded

Comment: error at this line  $CI->email->initialize($config);

Comment: You also post error which you received

Answer (score 0):

Because you said that it works fine locally it indicates that it is a problem with the code but rather with the server configuration.  It's hard to say what the exact issue is but I would do the following

- Check the server log files for any errors
- Make sure the you have enabled SSL in your php.ini by check that the following line is  - uncommented `extension=php_openssl.dll`
- Make sure that port 465 is open

Try those to start with and see what happens